# Flatten Java Object using Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatten

I have a class like this:

```java
class Student {
    String name;
    String age;
    List<Course> Courses;
}

class Course {
    String courseName;
    String teacher;
}
```

I have:

```java
List<Student> students
```

I want to get:

```java
List<Object> objects
```

with values Like this:

```
Kevin  22  CS   Rob
Kevin  22  MT   Chris
Mary   21  AT   Harry
Mary   21  AP   Henry
Mary   21  PP   Joe
Prak   25  null null
```

Whats the simplest way to do this using Java 8 `Streams`?
Can `flatMap` help?

Look at the last one. Even though `Prak` is not enrolled in any courses (i.e.`List<Course>` is empty), I want to get the record too, with just `Student`, along with other ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a new object flatted, yes, a combinations of flatMap and map will work, but checking if the `List` is empty or not:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course course1 = new Course("course 1", "teacher 1");
        Course course2 = new Course("course 2", "teacher 2");
        Course course3 = new Course("course 3", "teacher 3");
        Course course4 = new Course("course 4", "teacher 4");
        Student student1 = new Student("name 1", "15", Arrays.asList(course1, course2, course3, course4));
        Student student2 = new Student("name 2", "16", new ArrayList<>());
        Student student3 = new Student("name 2", "16", Arrays.asList(course1, course3));
        Student student4 = new Student("name 4", "17", new ArrayList<>());

        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(student1, student2, student3, student4);

    List<Objects> objects = students.stream().flatMap(student -> 
        student.getCourses().isEmpty() ?
            Stream.of(new Objects(student.getName(), student.getAge(), null, null)) :
            student.getCourses().stream().map(course -> new Objects(student.getName(), student.getAge(), course.getCourseName(), course.getTeacher()))
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        objects.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

class Course {
    String courseName;
    String teacher;

    public Course(String courseName, String teacher) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
}

class Student {
    String name;
    String age;
    List<Course> courses;

    public Student(String name, String age, List<Course> courses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}

class Objects{
    String name;
    String age;
    String courseName;
    String teacher;

    public Objects(String name, String age, String courseName, String teacher) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + this.name + " age: " + this.age + " course name: " + this.getCourseName() + " teacher: " + this.getTeacher();
    }
}
```

> output

```
name: name 1 age: 15 course name: course 1 teacher: teacher 1
name: name 1 age: 15 course name: course 2 teacher: teacher 2
name: name 1 age: 15 course name: course 3 teacher: teacher 3
name: name 1 age: 15 course name: course 4 teacher: teacher 4
name: name 2 age: 16 course name: null teacher: null
name: name 2 age: 16 course name: course 1 teacher: teacher 1
name: name 2 age: 16 course name: course 3 teacher: teacher 3
name: name 4 age: 17 course name: null teacher: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code and I have also pasted the output at the bottom. Here instead of using List we can have List of some object having four string instance variable.

List c1= Arrays.asList(new Course("CS", "Rob"), new Course("MT", "Chris"));

```
    List<Course> c2= Arrays.asList(new Course("AT", "Harry"), new Course("AP","Henry"),  new Course("PP", "Joe"));

    List<Course> c3= Arrays.asList(new Course());
    List<Student> s1= Arrays.asList(new Student("Kevin", "22", c1), new Student("Mary", "21", c2), new Student("Prak", "25", c3));

   List<String> list= s1.stream().flatMap(s-> s.getCourses().stream().map(d1-> s.getName()+" "+s.getAge()+" "+""+d1.getCourseName()+" "+d1.getTeacher()) ).collect(Collectors.toList());
   list.forEach( System.out::println);
```

Output :

Kevin 22 CS Rob
Kevin 22 MT Chris
Mary 21 AT Harry
Mary 21 AP Henry
Mary 21 PP Joe
Prak 25 null null